# Forcing ALL plugin Admin menus into a separate menu

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin-menu

I'd like to move ALL of the menu's generated by various plugins such as ACF, Layerslider, WPMU Dev etc, into a separate menu structure. In short, I'd prefer an item called "Plugin menu's" and below that have all the items relating to plugins. Sure, it'll add a third level to the structure, but that seems like a tiny problem imho.

I've googled but can't find anything on the subject.

The reasons I have for doing this, is A) to clean up the WP Admin considerably and B) to always know where plugin menu's are, especially when testing something new.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://unserkaiser.com/blog/2011/12/01/wordpress-admin-menu-in-detail/) as a starting point. Then come back and show us where you are stuck with moving menu entries. The thing that I think is extremely hard is to distinguish between core and 3rd party menu items. Have you any idea on that? Everything as [edit] to the question, please.

Comment: Ok I'll have a read-through later. And I agree, I think that programmatically finding which are plugins, will be hard. I honestly figured that WP would add a flag or something to each menu item that was not from Core, but perhaps that was wishful thinking... :-)